# Request[] is null but have a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, request

I have this `request`. But when checking its value it is null. How can this be when I've set `value="edit_show"`?

```
@{
    bool edit_show = false;

    if (Request["btn"] == "edit_show")
    {
        edit_show = true;
    }
}

    <button type="submit" name="btn" id="edit_show" value="edit_show" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
```

Comment: I don't believe request works on buttons.  try putting the same thing into a hidden input and see if the request works then

Comment: @MattBodily - I believe they do. Cause I have other buttons with Request[] that works without problems ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` values have different behaviours depending on the browser. From [w3schools HTML button tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> Tips and Notes Note: If you use the  element in an HTML form,
>   different browsers may submit different values. Use  to create
>   buttons in an HTML form.

If you need to post an additional value with your button, create a `<input type='hidden' .../>` and its value will be posted. Or create your button using a `<input type='submit' .../>`

In your case, you can't use the second solution (the proposed in w3schools) because you have embedded hmtl inside your button, unless you change your desing.

Of course, the button must be inside the same form that the hidden files that you want to post.

Comment: Your question triggered something, I've forgotten to wrap my button in a `form`. Thanks you ^^

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've changed the answer to include that detail.